# Django custom User model authentication

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

Since i'm not using the Auth User from Django, I have my own model CustomUser and I want make authentication on site through this model (CustomUser does not inherit from User model and not related to it at all).

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 72, unique = True)
    #stuff...
```

I checked https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend and the main thing I don't understand is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Do I need to import Django User if I want to use my CustomUser?

I can't find a good tutorial which explains how you can use Django without standard Auth User.

***edit:
I know I can extend with User. But I just don't want that. The question is not: what is the best way to use User and store additional information etc etc. I appreciate it though.
BUT how I can use a Custom User without using Auth User. Even if I don't have a reason to. ***

If it is possible I want to know how.

Comment: What do you mean by "use a Custom User"? Will you be able to use `login_required` decorator? Yes, if your `CustomUser` provides `is_authenticated` method, no overwise. Will you be able to use permissions? No. And so on. What part of Django auth system do you want to use?

Comment: Normally you would use the Auth User to create users. I use CustomUser to create users as shown above. I want to use login_required and is_authenticated. No permissions.

Comment: I have been going crazy trying to answer this myself. I need both the Auth User AND a custom "Auth Account". I hear everyone saying "stuff it in the User table and set up an "Account" group" but I do not want that. What happened to you @nelsonvarela? Did you ever find the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @nelsonvarela do you find any right answer for this question till now.I f yes then please help me in same problem

Answer (score 1):

The whole Django auth system is tightly coupled with `django.contrib.auth.models.User`, so you should use it in the backend. Quoting [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

> > For now, the best way to deal with this is to create a Django User object for each user that exists for your backend

But the main question here is: what is so special about your `CustomUser` that you can't implement with normal `User` model (may be extended)? In 99% of cases using `User` is the best way.

Comment: I dont have a special reason. I just want to know how i can do this

Comment: A use-case I can think of would be device authentication.  I might have a service that needs to authenticate devices AND users.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post.

> Most of the Django projects I’ve worked on need to store information about each user in addition to the standard name and email address held by the contrib.auth.models.User model.
>
> If you’re using trunk as of revision 7477 (26th April 2008), your model classes can inherit from an existing model class. Additional fields are stored in a separate table which is linked to the table of the base model. When you retrieve your model, the query uses a join to get the fields from it and the base model.

http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

And this post.

> Copy the auth application over into your own project and modify it to your needs. This avoids some of the maintenance troubles, but removes the utility of Django bundling an auth system in the first place. It can also cause compatibility problems with other applications which expect the User model to be in django.contrib.auth.

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/

Comment: You could quote some essential points of the link to show people what it is before they're going to click the link.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answers your question:

From 'https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model':

> Substituting a custom User model
>   New in Django 1.5.
>   Some kinds of projects may have authentication requirements for which Django’s built-in User model is not always appropriate. For instance, on some sites it makes more sense to use an email address as your identification token instead of a username.
>
> Django allows you to override the default User model by providing a value for the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting that references a custom model:
>
> AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
>   This dotted pair describes the name of the Django app (which must be in your INSTALLED_APPS), and the name of the Django model that you wish to use as your User model.

Of course there are some requisite warnings to consider (available at the above link), but this is looking like a good answer to your question: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#auth-user-model

There are also some custom model compliance expectations to consider (too many to list here): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Unless there can be more than one value for AUTH_USER_MODEL (I doubt that is sane), then I think I will need to build my own custom authentication backend: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

I hope this helps any other lost souls out there that need distinct User and Device authentication schemes (perhaps because of some pre-existing spec that makes messy what could be soooo easy).

Cheers!