# Device authentication in django

Tags: django, authentication, device

I have a Device model in django and I would like to be able to authenticate it.

```
class Device(models.Model):
    device_key = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    udid = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

To be more specific, given the above Device model, I would like to be able to achieve something similar to TokenAuthentication (http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#tokenauthentication).

Sending a request to a login URL with the device_key and udid should return a token, which identifies the Device model, and can be used for further requests.

Note:

1. Devices are NOT Users. I already use the User model for different purposes.
2. This question is basically similar to asking how do I authenticate a custom user model in django, which does not have a decent answer either ([Django custom User model authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312772/django-custom-user-model-authentication))

Is there a "django" way to do this?

Comment: Could you not extend the user model using Model inheritance, else you will need to write your own authentication classes

Comment: Yep, write your own authentication code. Contrary to popular belief it's not difficult at all.

Comment: Any good references for doing so?

Comment: You can look at the source code of django taking inspiration from there. https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth